# Scroll to an element within a hidden div after slideDown

Tags: jquery, slidedown, js-scrollintoview

There's a hidden DIV (has a specific height) has a lot of selectable icon DIVs, This DIV shown up by slideDown jQuery function, I want to scroll into the selected nested icon DIV (in the middle of the hidden div which is not appear because of the height limitation) after slideDown .. so

After click on [trigger-btn] the hidden DIV shown up using slideDown function, So we test to get [offset().top] of [selectable icon's DIV] and apply it to [scrollTop] of [icons-list] but it went to a wrong position.

```
<div class="elements-container">
    <div class="trigger-btn"></div>

    <div class="hidden-div-wrapper">

        <select class="icons-library">...</select>

        <div class="find-icon">...</div>

        <div class="icons-list">

            <!-- Selectable Icon DIVs -->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it for a project once
https://jsfiddle.net/bimbonkens/3ssfvyms/

CSS

```
.slideable {
  background: #000;
  display: none;
}

.slideable div {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
}

.buffer {  
  background: #fff;
  height: 800px;
}

.target {  
  background: #cfc;
  height: 1200px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="slideable">
  <div class="buffer"></div>
  <div class="target"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on("click", function() {
    $('.slideable').slideDown({
    duration: 800,
    done: function() {
        $('body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $('.target').offset().top
      })
    }
  });
});
```

Also, if you have a position: fixed; header, then you will have to account for it's height:

```
scrollTop: $('.target').offset().top - fixed_element_height
```

**Edit**

fiddle with correct solution http://jsfiddle.net/bimbonkens/p9huerde/

The key moment here is that offset().top gets the offset from the top of the whole document, so to account for that, i subtracted the position().top of parent div

Comment: Many thanks for you, But you scroll the whole body to show the div, I don't want this .. i want to scroll into view an element inside the hidden div.

Comment: what do you mean? i scrolled to an element inside the initially hidden div, isn't that what you wanted? maybe try to rephrase your question a bit, i have trouble understanding T_T

Comment: Many thanks, You're right i forgot to mention that the hidden div has a specific height and the icons in hundreds so i must specify the height, i want scroll into view the icon not appear in the middle (for example) within the hidden div.

Comment: but i scrolled not in the middle of div, but to the div with class "target"
so you need this

scrollTop: $('your_icon_selector').offset().top

Comment: you can scroll to any element with this piece of code :) just specify the selector to which you want to scroll. if you want it to be not at the top of the page, but anywhere else, you have to calculate that height and add or subtract from offset().top